# Why is Vue Js computed message not showing up in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vue.js

I'm trying to compute a message in a Vue instance so that it shows up in a h1 element - reversed, but it's not showing up. Any idea why?

```js
    new Vue({
      el: '#comp-prop2',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello World...again!'
      },
      computed: {
        reversedMessage() {
          return this.message.split('').reverse.join('');
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

   <div id="comp-prop2">
        <h1> {{ reversedMessage }} </h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its a basic example in vuejs : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `reverse()` not `reverse`

So like this

```
return this.message.split('').reverse().join('');
```

*`reverse()` is a method, you forgot the `()`

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/o9ed3go8/)

Comment: Its `reverse()` not `reverser()` :)